# Deleting unwanted package files

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage

I have a samsung galaxy ace, android 2.1, jailbroken. I had 48MB free space and tried to install a 46MB file but it says that the package files are incorrect or smth of the sort and doesn't install.

My problem now is that I have only 2MB free space and I have to locate where these new files are to delete them with root explorer. The play store doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score -1):

Well after searching randomly, I found it :
It's on the folder called `/data/cache`
Hope it helps